Handle dataframe with ~5 billion rows
I need to handle a DataFrame with about 5 billion rows and two columns, but apparently, R cannot create a DataFrame with more than 2^31 (2,147,483,648) rows. When I try to generate one with that dimension I get this error:
 Error in if (mirn && nrows[i] > 0L) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition: Warning message:
In attributes(.Data) <- c(attributes(.Data), attrib) :
  NAs introduced by coercion to integer range

Any suggestion?

Yo may have a look at: https://cran.r-project.org/view=HighPerformanceComputing

In other words, nrow(df) > .Machine$integer.max?

What R version are you using? 2^31 - 1 was the limit until R 3.0 (released in 2013). The long vectors FAQ gives more detail, and says that the current "sanity check" limit is 2^48, which is around 280 trillion. But you will need a 64-bit version of R and plenty of memory--the FAQ says a single vector exceeding 2^31 -1 in length will take 8Gb of memory for integer/boolean, and 16Gb for character. That said the High Performance Computing link is worth checking out, especially the Large memory and out-of-memory data section.

Take a look at the Arrow R package for reading large datasets. Maybe it can help you
https://arrow.apache.org/docs/3.0/r/articles/arrow.html

".Machine$integer.max" is actually 2^31, but I am running R version 4.4.0 x64 and I have 64gb of RAM. How can I change the ".Machine$integer.max"?

If you've gone through the link to the R Arrow package, you would find that you will need to first convert your data into .parquet format before you can read it into your R environment. Several billions of rows of data can be read in .parquet format, which you can then go on to analyze.

https://stackoverflow.com/q/55183203/190277

@GregorThomas looks like this is specifically a data.frame issue, e.g. x <- rep(1L, 1.5*2^31) works for me (I run out of memory at larger multipliers) but d <- data.frame(rep(1L, 2^31)) fails as described by the OP. (Won't fit in a matrix either: "data is too long".)

In any case OP is unlikely to have much headroom if they only have 64G - a vector of 1.1*2^31 integers is already 8.8 Gb, and floats are twice as big (so 4 columns of floating-point data of this length would be too much)

(8 bytes * 5e9 * 2 cols) = 40 Gb, so you could in principle read it in but you wouldn't be able to do very much with it (a single accidental copy would run out of memory)

@Jaime Please elaborate on what you mean by "handle".

Thanks for the suggestions. I will not read the df, the df will be generated through multiple iterations that organize the results from other analyses. The first column will store integers ranging between 1 and 1M, the second integers between 1 and 8K, and the third one floats with up to 4 digits in the integer part. The problem with using another type of structure is that the package (prioritize) where I will use it only accepts the df format. The solution for now is to resample original data (that comes from rasterized spatial data) to a coarse resolution to produce a lighter df

prioritizr? I don't see a prioritize package on CRAN ...

Sorry, autocorrect. Yes, prioritizr
